# TypeError when running update-manager on ubuntu 17.10

Tags: package-management, python, 17.10, update-manager

When I try to run update-manager then I receive the following error:

```
szymon@sm:~$ update-manager
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/defer/__init__.py", line 477, in _inline_callbacks
    result = gen.throw(result.type(result.value).with_traceback(result.traceback))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/backend/InstallBackendAptdaemon.py", line 67, in update
    _("Checking for updates…"), False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/defer/__init__.py", line 477, in _inline_callbacks
    result = gen.throw(result.type(result.value).with_traceback(result.traceback))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/backend/InstallBackendAptdaemon.py", line 159, in _show_transaction
    yield trans.run()
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Python.TypeError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/defer/__init__.py", line 477, in _inline_callbacks
    result = gen.throw(result.type(result.value).with_traceback(result.traceback))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/core.py", line 913, in _run
    yield self._check_auth()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/defer/__init__.py", line 477, in _inline_callbacks
    result = gen.throw(result.type(result.value).with_traceback(result.traceback))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/core.py", line 965, in _check_auth
    authorized = yield self._check_alternative_auth()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/defer/__init__.py", line 477, in _inline_callbacks
    result = gen.throw(result.type(result.value).with_traceback(result.traceback))
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'action_id'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/defer/__init__.py", line 477, in _inline_callbacks
    result = gen.throw(result.type(result.value).with_traceback(result.traceback))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/backend/InstallBackendAptdaemon.py", line 67, in update
    _("Checking for updates…"), False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/defer/__init__.py", line 477, in _inline_callbacks
    result = gen.throw(result.type(result.value).with_traceback(result.traceback))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/backend/InstallBackendAptdaemon.py", line 159, in _show_transaction
    yield trans.run()
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Python.TypeError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/defer/__init__.py", line 477, in _inline_callbacks
    result = gen.throw(result.type(result.value).with_traceback(result.traceback))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/core.py", line 913, in _run
    yield self._check_auth()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/defer/__init__.py", line 477, in _inline_callbacks
    result = gen.throw(result.type(result.value).with_traceback(result.traceback))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/core.py", line 965, in _check_auth
    authorized = yield self._check_alternative_auth()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/defer/__init__.py", line 477, in _inline_callbacks
    result = gen.throw(result.type(result.value).with_traceback(result.traceback))
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'action_id'


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/defer/__init__.py", line 390, in _next
    self.result = callback(self.result, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/defer/__init__.py", line 535, in gotResult
    _inline_callbacks(res, gen, deferred)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/defer/__init__.py", line 525, in _inline_callbacks
    deferred.errback()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/defer/__init__.py", line 352, in errback
    self._next()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/defer/__init__.py", line 408, in _next
    self.result.traceback)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 98, in apport_excepthook
    pr['_PythonExceptionQualifier'] = name
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/problem_report.py", line 652, in __setitem__
    raise TypeError("value for key %s must be a string, CompressedValue, or a file reference" % k)
TypeError: value for key _PythonExceptionQualifier must be a string, CompressedValue, or a file reference
```

It also happens when update-manager runs automatically on system start.

When I run update-manager with sudo then this error does not occur.

**Version info:**

```
szymon@sm:~$  update-manager --version
update-manager: version 1:17.10.11su

szymon@sm:~$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-9.20160110ubuntu5-amd64:core-9.20160110ubuntu5-noarch:printing-9.20160110ubuntu5-amd64:printing-9.20160110ubuntu5-noarch:security-9.20160110ubuntu5-amd64:security-9.20160110ubuntu5-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 17.10
Release:    17.10
Codename:   artful
```

**Actions performed so far:**

1. Reinstalled update-manager, python3-update-manager, update-manager-core, defer with synaptic.

Any other steps I can perform to fix that?
Should update-manager use python3.6 by default?

**EDIT 1: add pip3 list output**

```
szymon@sm:~/Projects/aurelia/contact-manager$ pip3 list
DEPRECATION: The default format will switch to columns in the future. You can use --format=(legacy|columns) (or define a format=(legacy|columns) in your pip.conf under the [list] section) to disable this warning.
asn1crypto (0.23.0)
certifi (2017.4.17)
cffi (1.11.2)
chardet (3.0.4)
command-not-found (0.3)
configobj (5.0.6)
cryptography (2.1.4)
defer (1.0.4)
defusedxml (0.5.0)
distro-info (0.0.0)
future (0.16.0)
idna (2.5)
jira (1.0.10)
junitparser (1.0.0)
keyring (10.5.0)
oauthlib (2.0.1)
pbr (3.1.1)
pep8 (1.7.1)
pip (9.0.1)
pycparser (2.18)
python-debian (0.1.30)
requests (2.18.1)
requests-oauthlib (0.8.0)
requests-toolbelt (0.8.0)
SecretStorage (2.3.1)
setuptools (36.6.0)
six (1.10.0)
tabulate (0.8.2)
ubuntu-drivers-common (0.0.0)
unattended-upgrades (0.1)
urllib3 (1.21.1)
wheel (0.29.0)
```

Comment: Did you have played with `pip3`? It seems that you have mixed Python environment (you have `/usr/local/lib/python3.6` and `/usr/lib/python3`).

Comment: Yes, some time ago I was doing some stuff over there and looks like screwed something up. Is it possible to fix that? I don't remember what I have exactly done.

Comment: Please update your question with output of `pip3 list`.

Comment: I have updated the question with pip3 list result. @N0rbert do you see any incorrect things in there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that problem is caused by `defer` package, `update-manager` has 15  messages about it.

Try to remove it with

```
sudo pip3 uninstall defer==1.0.4
```

And reinstall one from repository

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-defer
```

Comment: Yeey, looks like that helped. Thank you very much :)